# How to parse JSON in Standard SQL BigQuery?

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

After streaming some json data into BQ, we have a record that looks like:

```
"{\"Type\": \"Some_type\", \"Identification\": {\"Name\": \"First Last\"}}"
```

How would I extract the `type` from this? E.g. I would like to get `Some_type`.

I tried all possible combinations shown in https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions without success, namely, I thought:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(raw_json , "$[\"Type\"]") as parsed_type FROM `table` LIMIT 1000
```

is what I need. However, I get:

Invalid token in JSONPath at: ["Type"]

Picture of rows preview

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Below example is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, "{\"Type\": \"Some_type\", \"Identification\": {\"Name\": \"First Last\"}}" raw_json UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '{"Type": "Some_type", "Identification": {"Name": "First Last"}}'
)
SELECT id, JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(raw_json , "$.Type") AS parsed_type
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row id  parsed_type  
1   1   Some_type    
2   2   Some_type
```

See below update example - take a look at third record which I think mimic your case

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, "{\"Type\": \"Some_type\", \"Identification\": {\"Name\": \"First Last\"}}" raw_json UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '''{"Type": "Some_type", "Identification": {"Name": "First Last"}}''' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, '''"{\"Type\": \"


                     null1\"}"
  '''
)
SELECT id, 
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(REGEXP_REPLACE(raw_json, r'^"|"$', '') , "$.Type") AS parsed_type
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row id  parsed_type  
1   1   Some_type    
2   2   Some_type    
3   3   null1
```

Note: I use `null1` instead of `null` so you can easily see that it is not a `NULL` but rather string `null1`

Comment: I know it very odd, but when I do the insert of data like in the answer, it works and parses the correct information. But when the same data is the column, I get nulls back.

Comment: can you show example of few rows in an **image** with result pane in Table mode - so we see what exactly data we are dealing with

Comment: I added the image, I'm guessing I need to de-quote it before calling `JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR`

Comment: the picture you just added  - is it in JSON preview or Table preview?

Comment: Its a table preview, Json preview is `"raw_json": "\"{\\\"Type\\\": \\\"`